# update to a specific tag in liquibase

Tags: database, version-control, liquibase

I know that I can include a version tag in my changelog by having a changeset

```xml
<changeSet id="1234" author="John">
    <tagDatabase tag="version_1"/>
</changeSet>
```

and that will allow me to rollback a database to version_1.

If I have a brand new database, is it possible to run update and just target up to a tag? I know that I could do a full update and then rollback, but that's a bit awkward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**
There is now an updateToTag command. See https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/updatetotag.html

**Original:**
There isn't currently a way to update to a tag. Liquibase assumes that the changelog matches your code and so you wan to make sure everything is ran. Normally if you want to only have portions of a changelog ran you would use multiple changeLogs or code branches with different changelog versions.

You can use updateCount to run a certain number of changeSets, but you need to know the number. You could also use the  tag which will halt changeSet execution at a certain point (possibly controlled with contexts or precoditions), but it is not tied to the tag functionality.

Answer (score 1):

They now have a new attribute for liquibase command. Just do:

```sh
liquibase updatetotag <tagname>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer